# How to add Custom Field at Product Edit/Save Page?

Tags: magento2, product, custom-field

I want to add Custom Field at Product Edit Page(Admin Side) like related/upsell/crosssell product i want to add Custom Products for it, found much similar solution but it's not working at all,If you know how to, Please help me out..

```
<?php


namespace CustomField\Ui\DataProvider;


use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;



class Fields extends AbstractModifier
{

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return $data;
}

/**
 * @param array $meta
 * @return array
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    $meta = array_replace_recursive(
        $meta,
        [
            'yash' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Add to Custom Products'),
                            'collapsible' => true,
                            'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'data.ktpl',
                            'sortOrder' => 10
                        ],
                    ],
                ],

            ],
        ]
    );


    return $meta;
}
protected function getButtonSet()
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'formElement' => 'container',
                    'componentType' => 'container',
                    'label' => false,
                    'content' => 'This ',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ];
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your code here?

Comment: https://store.magenest.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-product-edit-pages-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create file InstallData.php

*We will start with the InstallData class which located in `app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Setup/InstallData.php`. The content for this file:*

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

}
```

**Step 2: Define the install() method**

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

}
```

**Step 3: Create custom attribute**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

> Run the upgrade script php `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to install the
>   module and the product attribute sample_attribute will be created.
>   After run upgrade complete, please run php `bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy -f` and go to product from admin to check
>   the result. it will show like this:

[image]

**Reference link** : [Magento 2 Add Product Attribute Programmatically](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically.html)

Comment: Not attribute want to add Custom FIeld like ADding  Related Product!!

Comment: This does not answer the question posed.